# How to limit the parameter to a specific number when it's taking in list?

Tags: python

```
def is_triangle (a,b,c):
    if (a + b) >= c and  (c + b) >= a and (b+c) >= a:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0 

tri = open('triangles.txt','r')
tri_2 = tri.readlines()
input_numbers = list(map(lambda i: int, tri_2))
ans_list = []
result = is_triangle (*input_numbers)
ans_list.append(result)
print(" ")
print(*ans_list, sep = " ")
```

The goal of program is to take a list from  a text file and return 1 or 0 from the function `is_triangle`, 1 meaning that it is a triangle and 0 meaning it's not. 
There are probably other problems with my code. But the main problem is that I received the message `TypeError: is_triangle() takes 3 positional arguments but 25 were given.` So I realized that the parameters are taking in too many arguments.  I was wondering if there was a way to limit the number of arguments from a list.

```
403 203 586
794 919 542
510 924 453
258 116 158
1316 2613 671
721 369 1725
493 929 1177
747 606 834
```

Another thing that I realized was that the text file is creating a list within a list.

Comment: `result = is_triangle (*input_numbers[:3])`? That will only consider the 1st 3 numbers in the list.

Comment: Your issue is that you’re doing all lines in one call to `is_triangle`.  (Your `map` is also wrong: your `lambda` always returns `int` *itself*.)

Comment: Thank you, very much. Now the problem is that the code is taking a list that within a list as one argument.  Is it possible for the function to take the list that is within the list as three arguments for the parameters?

Comment: One of your triangle inequalities is repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at what is happening in these lines:

```
tri = open('triangles.txt','r')
tri_2 = tri.readlines()
```

If you examine what is in `tri_2`, you should see something like this:

```
tri_2[0] = "403 203 586"
tri_2[1] = "794 919 542"
…
```

This means that `tri_2` will have a size of 25 (or however many lines there are in your file), making `input_numbers` also have 25 entries, and then you end up passing 25 arguments to `is_triangle`.

As others have pointed out, you should instead go line by line, extract the numbers from each line, then call `is_triangle`. It should be similar to this:

```
...
ans_line = []
for line in tri_2:
    split_line = line.split()
    input_numbers = map(int, split_line)
    result = is_triangle(*input_numbers)
    ans_line.append(result)
...
```

Comment: @DavisHerring True, that's simpler. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Read and process line-by line:

```
with open('triangles.txt','r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `is_triangle` to take in a list then unpack it you could just then read your file into a list of lists, convert those to sublists into `ints`, and then pass each sublist i.e `[403, 203, 586]` into `is_triangle`

```
def is_tri(x):
    a, b, c = x
    if (a + b) >= c and  (c + b) >= a and (b+c) >= a:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

with open('triangles.txt') as f:
    content = [line.split() for line in f]

content = [list(map(int, i)) for i in content]
ans_list = [is_tri(i) for i in content]
print(' ')
print(*ans_list, sep = ' ')
#
# 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So the lines of your textfile consist of 3 numbers separated by white spaces and you want to read the file, apply the `is_triangle` function on each line so that the output is consists of a sequence of zeroes and ones.

There are many ways you can achieve this. First, I would modify the function as follows:

```
def is_triangle (row):
    if (row[0] + row[1]) >= row[2] and  (row[0] + row[2]) >= row[1] and (row[1]+row[2]) >= row[1]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0  


""" I would read all the text file into one big list
    This might be computationally expensive.
"""
```

1. Using `list` and `map`

```
res = []
with open('triangle.txt', 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        res.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])

result = list(map(is_triangle, res))
print(result)
>>>[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

2. Using the `apply` method of `pandas dataframe`s. I think this is what you may want to do with large text files. We apply the function on every row.

   ```
    data = pd.read_table('triangle.txt', names = list('abc'), delimiter= '\s', engine = 'python')
    data.head()


        a     b    c
    0  403  203    586
    1  794  919    542
    2  510  924    453
    3  258  116    158
    4  1316 2613   671


    data['IsTriangle'] =data.apply(is_triangle, axis = 1)
    data.head()

        a    b      c  IsTriangle
    0  403   203   586    1
    1  794   919   542    1
    2  510   924   453    1
    3  258   116   158    1
    4  1316  2613  671    0
   ```